# Specify a type to be a value type

Tags: swift

In Swift 5.9, there is a new warning:

> Forming 'UnsafeRawPointer' to a variable of type '[T]'; this is likely
> incorrect because 'Element' may contain an object reference.

Because there is no type enforcement on T, it warns us about unsafe usage when we pass in a reference type value.

Here is my code:

```
func aFunc<T>(values: [T]) -> MTLBuffer {
  let buffer = makeMTLBuffer()
  let bufferPointer = buffer.contents()
  memcpy(bufferPointer, values, size)
  return buffer
}
```

Is there any way we can specify `T` to be a value type, so that it will silence this warning? We have `: AnyObject` to specify a reference type, but I couldn't find a way to specify value type.

Comment: How about taking a `UnsafeRawPointer` instead, and do the "array to pointer" conversion on the caller's side?

Comment: Just mentioning that this has been discussed in the Swift forum, e.g. here: https://forums.swift.org/t/value-type-bound-protocols/6640.

Comment: @Sweeper yes that silences the warning, but this is a function inside a class using generic type T, so by doing so, I lost the safety of type check.

Comment: Your code says otherwise :) I’d suggest editing the code to show your actual situation.

Comment: sorry, `T` is declared at the class level, I made it function level for shorter code example :D.

Comment: I can get around with this `_ = values.withUnsafeBufferPointer { pointer in memcpy(bufferPointer, pointer.baseAddress, memorySize) }`. The app is very performance-sensitive. Does this wrapper method has some performance overhead?